# from sklearn import svm ImportError: cannot import name lsqr

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error when I import svm modules. I have installed scipy as per the instructions. Here is the code and error.

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..linear_model.base import LinearClassifierMixin, SparseCoefMixin
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .base import LinearRegression
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 23, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr
ImportError: cannot import name lsqr
```

Comment: This is impossible to understand. Please format better and include what you did along with the error message.

Comment: Apologize. This is my first time posting. I have edited it. Hope this is better.

Comment: That is much better. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Can you run the same import from console? perhaps you should re-install scipy.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this problem, it is caused by the mismatch between the scipy version and the scikit-learn version, you can read [the 'Dependency' section](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.13.1) for scikit learn version 0.13.1 or any other version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn).